# Lengthy Japanese Filenames sent as attachment using javamail are getting corrupted

Tags: unix, encoding, jakarta-mail, filenames

We are sending files with lengthy Japanese filenames ( >30 characters) as attachments with mails.
We are using Javamail to send mails. Before adding the attchment to the mail, the fielnames are being encoded in Shift-JIS using the following piece of code.

fileName=MimeUtility.encodeText(fileName,"SJIS",null);

This however works fine if the name of the file is small (Japanese). It works fine in windows, not in unix. Even I tried with utf-8 encoding as well.

Any pointers/solutions to the above problem?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you seen this [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#encodefilename)?  Do you have an example of the corruption?  What does the message look like before you send it?  What does it look like when you receive it?  Use the Message.writeTo method to write the message to a file to compare.

Comment: Yes I can give the sample test example below
messageBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText("lundi ウエストロージャパン＜法令改正アラート.html","SJIS","B"));

I receive a filename attachment with shrinking the length as “lundi ウエストロージャパ”

The attachement content as below

=?SJIS?B?g5OBg5ZAl9+J/JCzg0GDiYFbg2cuaHRtbA==?="; charset=ISO-2022-JP
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?SJIS?B?bHVuZGkgg0WDR4NYg2eDjYFbg1eDg4Nw?=\
\
 =?SJIS?B?g5OBg5ZAl9+J/JCzg0GDiYFbg2cuaHRtbA==?="

PGh0bWw+CiA8aGVhZD4KIDwvaGVhZD4KIDxoMT4xMjE8L2gxPgogPGJvZHkgc3R5bGU9J21hc

Comment: I think your post got corrupted.  Can you edit the original question and add this information?  I just want to see the MIME headers before and after, not the original Japanese characters.

Comment: One more finding that might help. With java-mail-1.4.jar, I could able to get the successful filename with 77 characters (SJIS encoding) and 54 characters (utf-8 encoding)

Comment: messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
messageBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(fileName,"SJIS",null));

Comment: Which JavaMail version fails?  Still waiting to see the MIME headers, not the code that sets them.  Again, I want to see the header **before** you send the message, and **after** you receive the (corrupted) message.  Use Message.writeTo to get the entire MIME content of the message.